# Datapipeline task stuck in WAITING_FOR_RUNNER state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I have created a simple ShellCommandActivity which echos some text. It runs on a plain ec2 (vpc) instance. I see that the host has spinned up but it never executes the tasks and the task remains in `WAITING_FOR_RUNNER` status. After all the retries I get this error

```
Resource is stalled. Associated tasks not able to make progress.
```

I followed this [troubleshoot-link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-check-when-run-fails.html#dp-waiting-for-runner) but it didn't resolve my problem.

Here is the json description of the pipeline:

```
{
  "objects": [
    {
      "resourceRole": "DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole",
      "role": "DataPipelineDefaultRole",
      "name": "ec2-compute",
      "id": "ResourceId_viWO9",
      "type": "Ec2Resource"
    },
    {
      "failureAndRerunMode": "CASCADE",
      "resourceRole": "DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole",
      "role": "DataPipelineDefaultRole",
      "pipelineLogUri": "s3://xyz-logs/",
      "scheduleType": "ONDEMAND",
      "name": "Default",
      "id": "Default"
    },
    {
      "name": "EchoActivity",
      "id": "ShellCommandActivityId_kc8xz",
      "runsOn": {
        "ref": "ResourceId_viWO9"
      },
      "type": "ShellCommandActivity",
      "command": "echo HelloWorld"
    }
  ],
  "parameters": []
}
```

What could be the problem here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some details about the Image used for Ec2 resource?

Comment: @franklinsijo I did not configure any specific image (see the json). I think it must be using some default.

Comment: @franklinsijo according to this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-ec2resource.html the default AMI for eu-west is ami-c7c0d6b3

Comment: Sorry, I assumed it was voluntarily removed. Does the spinned up instance pass the `2/2 checks`?

Comment: @franklinsijo yes, the checks pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. The routing table in the VPC subnets was not properly configured.

To be specific, in my case the routing table didn't have 0.0.0.0/0 mapped to an internet-gateway. When I added this mapping, everything started working.

Comment: Could you provide more detailed information about changes you have made to fix the problem?